# Racing Condition in Two Backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, race-condition, amazon-ec2

I am writing a multiplayer realtime game. I have a website for registration and player stats displaying, and a game for actually game data. Here are some options I have on my backend design and My concerns ():

1. Use same backend for game and website: not secure.
2. Use different backend but same database for game and website, so user will register on website and play on game: will this design cause race situation when both backend are writing to Mongodb (like new user registration and user stats change at the same time from both end? )?
3. Use different backend and different database: These two database has to synchronize since game players comes from website and website stats comes from game.

Comment: You can use **one backend** and **one database** for both: game and site. It can be not secure, only if you add architecture mistakes in that backend. What about parallel writing in database, any modern database can handle that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use one database with three collections. The first collection has player registration (signup, login, logout, session). The second collection keeps player stats and the third collection has game-play. If you use [Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) to store the game-play data you can use the MongoDB aggregation framework to generate your stats which can them be written to the second collection.

You can then shard the collections as the load grows (you will probably need to shard the game play collection first).